# Show line number when search a single file

Tags: ack

`ack` usually shows line numbers with file name,

```
$ ack searchme
filename
1:searchme
```

but it doesn't when search a single file,

```
$ ack searchme filename
searchme
```

It's easy to show line numbers with `grep`

```
$ grep -n searchme filename
1:searchme
```

Can I show the line numbers when I search a single file with `ack`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue was raised as a bug for `ack` [Output line numbers of matches when acking a single file #244](https://github.com/petdance/ack/issues/244) with the following response:

> All future development on ack is happening on
>   https://github.com/petdance/ack2. This issue has been moved here:
>   [Do we need an option for forcing the printing of the line number? #196](https://github.com/petdance/ack2/issues/196)

The status of the **ack2** request is **open**.

[Output line numbers of matches when acking a single file #244](https://github.com/petdance/ack/issues/244) does include a patch which may resolve the issue as well as the following comment:

> Nevertheless using `--with-filename` option will always print file name
>   and therefore line numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You can append "more" to your command and it will display the file name and line numbers for each result

Example:
ack test test.c more 
test.c
12: something here that had test
17: something here that had test
32: something here that had test